# Local da exibição da mensagem

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Observem a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Reparem que a mensagem de validação aparece na parte superior, como faço pra que ela apareça ao lado dos campos correspondentes e não apareçam mais na parte de cima ?

Answer (score 0):

Tentou incluir um message para o inputText?

```
<h:inputText id="txt" value="#{bean.text}" />
<p:message for="txt" />
```